# Merge videos at specific frame or time

Tags: ios, swift, avcomposition

Here is my scenario:

- Step 1: user selects video A from the list
- Step 2: user plays video A
- Step 3: user pauses video A
- Step 4: user selects video B from a secondary list
- Step 5: user inserts video B after the last frame where video A was paused

How can I insert video B after a given frame or duration of video A?
Can AVMutableComposition help in this scenario? I'm seeing examples of merging but only at the end of the previous video.

If there is no clean way to do it, should I break video A into two pieces (at the selected frame), add video B in the middle and then merge the 3 of them?